# Laravel project blank login screen

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, wamp, laravel-artisan

I have a laravel project that is basically a web application. I started working on a new machine so had to setup the whole thing again. However I dont know what I did that I shouldnt have, but now when I try to access the website/application, I just end up on a blank default laravel page with login and register on the top right of the screen. i am using wamp and basically I started the server in the project folder with

```
php artisan serve
```

then when I tried to access my project website with:

```
localhost:8000
```

as the url in the browser, I had en error saying that 'No application encryption key has been specified'. So i searched a bit on that error and then found out I had to do the following command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After doing that command, and trying to access localhost:8000, I end up on that random login page. I have no login or anything about that on my website/application. It should go straight to the homepage(tried to manually enter localhost:8000/home with the same result)

thank you

Comment: Check permissions on /bootstrap and /storage. and check the log files

Comment: checked the permissions and its everybody allowed

Comment: and php log file

Comment: where is this at

Comment: I don't use windows nor WAMP so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Check your route/web.php file to understand what view is served for the root ( / ) of your website. Then check the view file and try commenting stuff and maybe echo some string to confirm that you are editing the correct file. From there try to understand what's the error (if there is one) from what you say it looks like a blank template pageor maybe only the header loads then yhe contents stop loading for an error. Make sure to set debug mode in your .env or config.php and activate error logs, also check the database connection settings

Answer (score 1):

The Url wont return the defaulh homepgae because you already ran this command on your command line. php artisan make:auth. The login/register page will remain the default home page. Register a user and login, you will be redirected to the homepage you were expecting.

Comment: By default you wouldn't get to a login page in Laravel if you haven't ran the command. However you can run the command, lets see if there's any error.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your routes file (routes.php or web.php depending on your laravel version). there you may find `Auth::routes();`. comment this part and check once.